# hstore value with space

Tags: postgresql, space, hstore

I am using Postgresql V 9.1:

```
SELECT 'k=>name, v=>Nava Ratna Secondary School'::hstore;
```

This code returns error:

```
ERROR:  Syntax error near 'R' at position 17
LINE 1: SELECT 'k=>name, v=>Nava Ratna Secondary School'::hstore;
               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: Syntax error near 'R' at position 17
SQL state: XX000
Character: 8
```

And filling spaces in 'Nava Ratna Secondary School' as 'Nava_Ratna_Secondary_School' or removing them 'NavaRatnaSecondarySchool' works.

But I need to store the v=Nava Ratna Secondary School with spaces. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'k=>name, v=>"Nava Ratna Secondary School"'::hstore;
```

When there are single quotes in the values or in the keys the easiest is to use dollar quote:

```
SELECT $$k=>"name", v=>"St. Xavier's Academy"$$::hstore;
```

Or the more widespread escaping:

```
SELECT 'k=>"name", v=>"St. Xavier''s Academy"'::hstore;
```

Comment: ["Double-quote keys and values that include whitespace, commas, =s or >s."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

Comment: Thank You! It works. I am new to the SQL coding. What's difference between using "" or '' in this context?. I need to learn basics.

Comment: @Ram Check [string constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

Comment: SELECT 'k=>"name", v=>$$St. Xavier's Academy$$'::hstore;

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto   (SELECT 'k=>"name", v=>"St. Xavier's Academy"'::hstore;) contains single quote in Xavier's. I read the string constants doc suggested by you and guessed it might work with dollar-quoted string constant and tried  (SELECT 'k=>"name", v=>$$St. Xavier's Academy$$'::hstore;) but it gets error. Please suggest for this case.

Comment: $k = $t->attributes()->k;
                    $v = $t->attributes()->v;
                //replace single quote with double quote to avoid hstore sql error
                $k= str_replace("'","''",$k)."\n";
                $v= str_replace("'","''",$v)."\n";
                
                $tag_str = "'k => " . '"' . $k . '"' . ", v => " . '"' . $v . '"' . "' ";
                $tag = " ( SELECT " . $tag_str . "::hstore) ";
                $a['tag'] = $tag;